# fgets + stdin : Is it possible to skip first 2 characters?

Tags: c

Story : HTML-form uses "`post`" method to send data. There is only `<textarea>` inside the `HTML-form` and it requires me to give it a name. I gave it the name "`a`". However because of this, the `stdin` starts with `a=`. In other words it contains 2 characters in the beginning of it that is not needed.

Mission : If possible, read the `stdin` starting from the `3rd` character.

Total characters in `stdin` : ( prints : `23` )

```
char* len;
len = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
fputs(len, stdout);
```

Reading `stdin` : ( `+1` for the `closure` )

```
char receive[24]; 
fgets(receive, 24, stdin);
```

Desired code : ( `-2` for `a=` )

```
char receive[22];
// If possible, read stdin starting from the 3rd character, 
// until the 24th character.
```

Comment: I'm afk so I can't test this, but I think ```receive = &receive[2]``` should do the trick.

Comment: @GasperStukelj No, you can't do that because `receive` is the name of an array. What you *can* do is `char *text = &receive[2]` and then use `text` as the array.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case, but as said, I couldn't test it. I used ```&array[*]``` before in ```printf```, but not for reassigning it. Thanks for correcting me, learned something new! Only one thing, I probably couldn't use ```text``` as an array if it would be declared as a string literal, right?

Comment: @GasperStukelj If `text` points to a string literal, then it's read-only. But you can still use array syntax (`text[i]`) to read characters from the string.

Comment: @user3386109 right, but I cannot modify it like I could modify an array of chars, like you said it's read-only.

Answer (score 3):

You can skip 2 characters either by:

`getchar() ; getchar() ;`

Not flexible, but will do the job.

However, from problem description, looks like you want to split input line into key value pairs, with '=' between key and value. Consider:

```
   char key[20], value[100] ;
   if ( scanf("%19[^=]=%99[^\n]", key, value) == 2 ) {
       // do something with key, value
   } ;
```

Comment: `scanf` is notoriously hard to use.  Your example does no bounds-checking, for example.  You should avoid using `scanf` if possible.

Comment: I agree that scanf is inappropriate for this problem. The question is about reading CGI input, and should be done with dedicated library (which will properly handle encoding, etc.). However, I believe that for the purpose of learning about basic IO in C, this may be OK. I'll edit the response to include bound checks.